# VBA - selecting a folder and referencing it as the path for a separate code

Tags: excel, vba

I'm able to use this code to select a folder:

```
Sub ChooseFolder()
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String

Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
With fldr
    .Title = "Select a Folder"
    .AllowMultiSelect = False
    .InitialFileName = strPath
    If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
    sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
End With

NextCode:
GetFolder = sItem
Set fldr = Nothing
End Sub
```

I also have this code, that works when the folder path is hardcoded. Basically, it gives me a list of file names and file paths that I use later in a separate section. Currently I have the hardcoded folder path commented out and I'm trying to use the above code to select the folder each time so that it is more user friendly.

```
Private Sub btn_LeaveReport()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Get the folder object
'Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder("D:\Administration\Time Sheets")
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)
i = 3

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```

However, I'm not sure how to get the two different code sets to work together. I'm guessing the only part I need to change is this:

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)
```

I have it as ChooseFolder which is the sub above for now but that is clearly not the way to go about it. I tried it with sItem as well but that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Your `ChooseFolder` Sub must be a Function that returns the path as a string for the code to work.

Comment: Related article: http://www.ammara.com/access_image_faq/browse_for_folder_dialog.html

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA - Folder Picker - set where to start](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to build on my comment with a better explanation, you have defined `ChooseFolder` as a Sub. Subs do not return values. However, you're using it as a Function when you do this:

```
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(ChooseFolder)
```

because you're passing the result of running `ChooseFolder` to the FSO's `GetFolder` function.

What you need to do is declare `ChooseFolder` as a Function.

Basically, replace your `ChooseFolder` Sub with this:

```
Function ChooseFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

and it should then do what you expect. The rest of your code is fine.

Comment: Wow thanks a lot it works great now and I now understand how functions and subs work together. Thanks!

Comment: A function is definitely the correct choice, but I would add to the answer: Sub can return values, at least sort of as long as you pass them `ByRef` (in some cases it makes sense to use it, but most likely not here).

Answer (score 0):

Make *ChooseFolder()* into a **function** and then reference it:

```
Public Function ChooseFolder()
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String

    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With

NextCode:
    ChooseFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function


Private Sub btn_LeaveReport()
Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim sFldr As String

'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

sFldr = ChooseFolder()
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(sFldr)
i = 3

'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.Files
    'print file name
    Cells(i + 1, 2) = objFile.Name
    'print file path
    Cells(i + 1, 3) = objFile.Path
    i = i + 1
Next objFile
End Sub
```