# VBA EXCEL To Prompt User Response to Select Folder and Return the Path as String Variable

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to write a VBA code where a dialog box would appear for the user to select where they want to save the files.
However, I just need the path value (e.g. `c:\Desktop\Values`) returned as a string variable so that I could use it in another function. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start

Comment: I want the full path name. Doesn't that just return Folder name?

Comment: no, you can get the full path (see Gary's answer)

Comment: In the answer that I posted in the link given above, if you add `Msgbox Ret` after `Ret = BrowseForFolder("C:\")` then you will get the folder path as string provided the user didn't press `Cancel`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Consider:

```
Function GetFolder() As String
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

and as jkf points out, from [Mr Excel](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/294728-browse-folder-vba.html)