# Having a user choose where to save an Excel workbook

Tags: excel, vba, save, xlsx, xlsm

I currently have a macro that will read data, print a results sheet, and then copy the data and results to a different workbook that is then saved as a regular .xlsx file as opposed to .xlsm. My code to save that book is as follows:

```
NewBook.Activate
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=NotNum & " Make Ready", _
     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
CTLBook.Activate
```

It brings up the new workbook I want to save, saves it under the name NotNum (a changing variable) and the string "Make Ready" and then brings back my original workbook so I can manipulate that further.

The save function works perfectly however it saves to my default folder (currently 'My Documents'). Is there a way I can code something before or after the save function that allows the user to choose where to save the document? Thanks

Comment: You can use the built in folder chooser dialog to ask the user for a location

Comment: [This thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392482/vba-excel-to-prompt-user-response-to-select-folder-and-return-the-path-as-string#26392703) may have the info you need

Comment: @TimWilliams I'm not experiences in the built in functionality of VBA. How would I call that dialogue?

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad That thread was exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like this:

```
Dim fldr As FileDialog
Dim sItem As String
Dim fileSaveName As String


Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder to Save to"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode

        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
        Set fldr = Nothing
```

sItem now has the path.

You can prompt for the file name:

```
fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(NotNum & " Make Ready", fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsx), *.xlsx")
```

This is the part you are after to complete:

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=sItem & "\" & fileSaveName, _
     FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook
```

I wove some of your naming into that and wove out some of the sub I was using that prints PDF files individually or all in one file.

EDIT:
This code was adapted from @Ozgrid and @Gary's Student . . .

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thank you good sir! Your code combined with the thread someone posted before gave me exactly what I need. I started running into syntax errors when I tried running it myself and your code helped me debug it and get it up and running.