# Create an array of file names in a folder - Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am currently using **Application.GetOpenFilename** with MultiSelect:=True to allow the user to select one or more files within a folder, then importing the data from all of the files into a worksheet. If multiple files are selected, the data from each file is appended to the data from the previous file until all of the selected files are imported.

I now have an instance where text files are stored in subfolders of a specific folder, with the subfolders created based on order numbers. I am now trying to define the parent folder as a variable, allow the user to input the subfolder name using **Application.InputBox**, then automatically import the data from all .txt files in the user-specified subfolder. I'm getting hung up with a Run-time error '53', File not found error. I know using the GetOpenFilename approach creates an array of the filenames, and I tried to replicate this by creating an array of the file names but I'm obviously missing something.

I'm basically trying to import all .txt files from something like the following:

C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails\ **user defined subfolder** \ *.txt

Code that works using **Application.GetOpenFilename**:

```
' Define that variables must be defined manually and will never be defined automatically
Option Explicit

    ' Hold specific variables in memory for use between sub-routines
    Public DDThreshold As Variant
    Public FileName As String
    Public FilePath As String
    Public OpenFileName As Variant
    Public OrderNum As Variant
    Public SaveWorkingDir As String
    Public SecondsElapsed As Double
    Public StartTime As Double
    Public TimeRemaining As Double

Sub Import_DataFile()

    ' Add an error handler
    ' On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Speed up this sub-routine by turning off screen updating and auto calculating until the end of the sub-routine
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Define variable names and types
    Dim DefaultOpenPath As String
    Dim SaveWorkingDir As String
    Dim OpenFileName As Variant
    Dim WholeFile As String
    Dim SplitArray
    Dim LineNumber As Integer
    Dim chkFormat1 As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n1 As Long
    Dim n2 As Long
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim RawData As String
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim rngFileList As Range
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim FileListRow As Long
    Dim aLastRow As Long
    Dim bLastRow As Long
    Dim cLastRow As Long
    Dim dLastRow As Long
    Dim destCell As Range

    ' Set the default path to start at when importing a file
    'On Error Resume Next
    If Len(Dir("C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

        DefaultOpenPath = "C:\"

        Else

        DefaultOpenPath = "C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails\"

    End If

    ' When opening another file for processing, this section will save the previously opened file directory
    'On Error Resume Next
    If SaveWorkingDir = CurDir Then

    ChDrive SaveWorkingDir
    ChDir SaveWorkingDir

    Else

    ChDrive DefaultOpenPath
    ChDir DefaultOpenPath

    End If

    ' Select the source folder and point list file(s) to import into worksheet
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
    OpenFileName = Application.GetOpenFilename( _
                   FileFilter:="AOI Inspection Results Data Files (*.txt), *.txt", _
                   Title:="Select a data file or files to import", _
                   MultiSelect:=True)


    ' Cancel the file import if the user exits the file import window or selects the Cancel button
    If Not IsArray(OpenFileName) Then

        MsgBox "" & vbNewLine & _
               "  No files were selected." & vbNewLine & _
               "" & vbNewLine & _
               "  Import AOI Inspection Results Data Files was aborted.", vbInformation, "File Import Cancelled"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ' Clear contents and reset formatting of cells in all worksheets
    aLastRow = Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    bLastRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
    cLastRow = Worksheets("Parsed Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E6:L14").ClearContents
        If aLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("B24:L" & aLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("B24:L" & aLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

        If bLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Q" & bLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Q" & bLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

        If cLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Parsed Data").Range("A1:Q" & cLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("Parsed Data").Range("A1:Q" & cLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E6:L9").NumberFormat = "@" 'Format cells to Text
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E10:L13").NumberFormat = "#,000" 'Format Cells to Number with commas
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E14:L14").NumberFormat = "0.00%" 'Format cells to Percent
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 8.09
    Worksheets("Parsed Data").Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.ColumnWidth = 8.09

    ' Update "Defect Density Threshold" to default value unless user entered a new value
        If DDThreshold > 0 Then
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E10").Value = DDThreshold

        Else
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E10").Value = "3,000,000"

        End If

    ' Save the user selected open file directory as the default open file path while the worksheet is open
    SaveWorkingDir = CurDir

    ' Timer Start (calculate the length of time this sub-routine takes to complete after selecting file(s) to import)
    StartTime = Timer

    ' Check selected input file format for YesTech AOI Inspection Results format
    Const chkYesTech = "[StartIspn]"
    For n1 = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
        fn = FreeFile
        Open OpenFileName(n1) For Input As #fn
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing ... " & OpenFileName(n1)

            WholeFile = Input(LOF(fn), #fn)
            SplitArray = Split(WholeFile, vbCrLf)
            LineNumber = 1
            chkFormat1 = SplitArray(LineNumber - 1)
            Close #fn

    If InStr(1, chkFormat1, chkYesTech, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    MsgBox OpenFileName(n1) & vbNewLine & " has been verified as a YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File"

    ' Import user selected YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File(s) to "Raw Data" worksheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    TargetRow = 0
    Set destCell = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1")
    For n2 = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
        fn = FreeFile
        Open OpenFileName(n2) For Input As #fn
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing ... " & OpenFileName(n2)

            ' Import data from file into Raw Data worksheet
            Do While Not EOF(fn)
            Line Input #fn, RawData
            If Len(Trim(RawData)) > 0 Then
                TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
                Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & TargetRow) = RawData
            End If

        Loop

        Next n2

        Close #fn

    Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1" & ":" & Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Address)

       With rngTarget

        .TextToColumns Destination:=destCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
         TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
         Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar:="|", _
         FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        End With

     Application.DisplayAlerts = True

        Else: MsgBox OpenFileName(n1) & vbNewLine & " is not a YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File."

        Exit Sub

        End If

    Next

    ' Create a number list (autofill) in Col A to maintain original import sort order
    dLastRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow).Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1") = "1"
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2") = "2"
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F1:Q" & dLastRow).NumberFormat = "0.0"

    ' List open file name(s) on spreadsheet for user reference
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Size = 9
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Bold = False
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

    FileListRow = 0
    Set rngFileList = Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9")
    For i = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)

        ' Add imported file name hyperlink to imported files in list of imported files
        ' rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0) = OpenFileName(i)
        rngFileList.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngFileList, _
        Address:=OpenFileName(i), _
        ScreenTip:="Imported File Number " & FileListRow + 1, _
        TextToDisplay:=OpenFileName(i)

        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E7").Value = OpenFileName(i)

        FileListRow = FileListRow + 1

        Next i

    ' Auto fit the width of columns for RAW Data
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' Timer Stop (calculate the length of time this sub-routine took to complete)
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    ' Turn screen updating and auto calculating back on since file processing is now complete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ' Display a message to report the sub-routine processing time after file selection including the number of data rows that have been imported
    MsgBox "AOI Inspection Results processed and imported in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds" & " ." & vbNewLine & _
           "      Successfully imported " & (TargetRow) & " rows of data.", vbInformation, "Data Import Results"

' Reset to defaults in the event of a processing error during the sub-routine execution
ErrorHandler:
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    ' Display a message to user including error code in the event of an error during execution
    MsgBox "An error number " & Err.Number & " was encountered!" & vbNewLine & _
           "Part or all of this VBA script was not completed.", vbInformation, "Error Message"
    End If

    Call Create_Report

End Sub
```

And here's my attempt at defining the parent folder, asking the user for the subfolder name using Application.InputBox, and loading all of the *.txt filenames into an array to be imported:

```
' Define that variables must be defined manually and will never be defined automatically
Option Explicit

    ' Hold specific variables in memory for use between sub-routines
    Public DDThreshold As Variant
    Public FileName As String
    Public FilePath As String
    Public OpenFileName As Variant
    Public OrderNum As Variant
    Public SaveWorkingDir As String
    Public SecondsElapsed As Double
    Public StartTime As Double
    Public TimeRemaining As Double

Sub OrderLineNum()

    ' Add an error handler
    'On Error GoTo ErrorHandler

    ' Speed up sub-routine by turning off screen updating and auto calculating
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    ' Define variable names and data types
    Dim DefaultOpenPath As String
    Dim SaveWorkingDir As String
    Dim OrderNum As Variant
    Dim GetFile As String
    Dim FileCount As Long
    Dim OpenFileName() As String
    ReDim OpenFileName(1000)
    Dim WholeFile As String
    Dim SplitArray
    Dim LineNumber As Integer
    Dim chkFormat1 As String
    Dim i As Long
    Dim n1 As Long
    Dim n2 As Long
    Dim fn As Integer
    Dim RawData As String
    Dim rngTarget As Range
    Dim rngFileList As Range
    Dim TargetRow As Long
    Dim FileListRow As Long
    Dim aLastRow As Long
    Dim bLastRow As Long
    Dim cLastRow As Long
    Dim dLastRow As Long
    Dim destCell As Range

    ' Set the default path to start at when importing a file
    ' On Error Resume Next
    If Len(Dir("C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails", vbDirectory)) = 0 Then

        DefaultOpenPath = "C:\"

        Else

        DefaultOpenPath = "C:\AOI_DATA64\SPC_DataLog\IspnDetails\"

    End If

    ' When opening another file for processing, save the previously opened file directory
    ' On Error Resume Next
    If SaveWorkingDir = CurDir Then

    ChDrive SaveWorkingDir
    ChDir SaveWorkingDir

    Else

    ChDrive DefaultOpenPath
    ChDir DefaultOpenPath

    End If

    ' Open InputBox to get order-line number from user
    OrderNum = Application.InputBox(prompt:= _
        "Enter Order-Line Number (e.g. 12345678-9)", _
        Title:="Password Required for This Function", _
        Default:="", _
        Left:=25, _
        Top:=25, _
        HelpFile:="", _
        HelpContextID:="", _
        Type:=2)

        If OrderNum = "" Then

            MsgBox "No Order Number entered. No data will be imported.", vbInformation, "Invalid Order Number"

            Exit Sub

        ElseIf OrderNum = "0" Then

            MsgBox "Order Number cannot be 0. No data will be imported.", vbInformation, "Invalid Order Number"

            Exit Sub

        ElseIf OrderNum = False Then

            MsgBox "User cancelled. No data will be imported.", vbInformation, "User Cancelled"

            Exit Sub

        End If

    ' Create an array of filenames found in the Order-Line Number sub-folder
    GetFile = Dir$(CurDir & "\" & OrderNum & "\" & "*.txt")
    Do While GetFile <> ""
        OpenFileName(FileCount) = GetFile
        GetFile = Dir$
        FileCount = FileCount + 1
    Loop

    ReDim Preserve OpenFileName(FileCount - 1)

    ' Save the user selected open file directory as the default open file path while the worksheet is open
    SaveWorkingDir = CurDir

    ' Timer Start (calculate the length of time this sub-routine takes to complete after selecting file(s) to import)
    StartTime = Timer

    ' Cancel the file import if the Order-Line Number subfolder doesn't exist
    If Not IsArray(OpenFileName) Then

        MsgBox "" & vbNewLine & _
               "  No files were selected." & vbNewLine & _
               "" & vbNewLine & _
               "  Import AOI Inspection Results Data Files was aborted.", vbInformation, "File Import Cancelled"
        Exit Sub

    End If

    ' Clear contents of cells and data worksheets
    aLastRow = Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlDown).Row
    bLastRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row
    cLastRow = Worksheets("Parsed Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlDown).Row

    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E6:L14").ClearContents
        If aLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("B24:L" & aLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("B24:L" & aLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

        If bLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Q" & bLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:Q" & bLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

        If cLastRow > 0 Then
        Worksheets("Parsed Data").Range("A1:Q" & cLastRow).ClearContents
        Worksheets("Parsed Data").Range("A1:Q" & cLastRow).ClearFormats
        End If

    ' Update "Defect Density Threshold" to default value unless user entered a new value
        If DDThreshold > 0 Then
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E10").Value = DDThreshold

        Else
        Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E10").Value = "3,000,000"

        End If

    'Check selected input file format for YesTech AOI Inspection Results format
    Const chkYesTech = "[StartIspn]"
    For n1 = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
        fn = FreeFile
        Open OpenFileName(n1) For Input As #fn
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing ... " & OpenFileName(n1)

            WholeFile = Input(LOF(fn), #fn)
            SplitArray = Split(WholeFile, vbCrLf)
            LineNumber = 1
            chkFormat1 = SplitArray(LineNumber - 1)
            Close #fn

    If InStr(1, chkFormat1, chkYesTech, vbBinaryCompare) > 0 Then
    MsgBox OpenFileName(n1) & vbNewLine & " has been verified as a YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File"

    ' Import user selected YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File(s) to "Raw Data" worksheet
    TargetRow = 0
    Set destCell = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1")
    For n2 = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
        fn = FreeFile
        Open OpenFileName(n2) For Input As #fn
        Application.StatusBar = "Processing ... " & OpenFileName(n2)

        Do While Not EOF(fn)
            Line Input #fn, RawData
            If Len(Trim(RawData)) > 0 Then
                TargetRow = TargetRow + 1
                Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B" & TargetRow) = RawData
            End If

        Loop

        Next n2

        Close #fn

     Set rngTarget = Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1" & ":" & Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("B1").End(xlDown).Address)

       With rngTarget

        .TextToColumns Destination:=destCell, DataType:=xlDelimited, _
         TextQualifier:=xlNone, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
         Semicolon:=True, Comma:=True, Space:=False, Other:=False, OtherChar:="|", _
         FieldInfo:=Array(1, 1), TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

        End With

        Else: MsgBox OpenFileName(n1) & vbNewLine & " is not a YesTech AOI Inspection Results Data File."

        Exit Sub

        End If

    Next

    ' Create a number list (autofill) in Col A to maintain original import sort order
    dLastRow = Worksheets("Raw Data").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow).Font.Color = RGB(200, 200, 200)
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1") = "1"
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A2") = "2"
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A2").AutoFill Destination:=Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("A1:A" & dLastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Range("F1:Q" & dLastRow).NumberFormat = "0.0"

    ' List open file name(s) on spreadsheet for user reference
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Name = "Calibri"
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Size = 9
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Bold = True
    Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9").Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)
    FileListRow = 0
    Set rngFileList = Worksheets("AOI Inspection Summary").Range("E9")
    For i = LBound(OpenFileName) To UBound(OpenFileName)
        Debug.Print OpenFileName(i)

        ' Add imported file name or hyperlink to imported files in list of imported files
        ' rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0) = OpenFileName(i)
        rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0).Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0), _
        Address:=OpenFileName(i), _
        ScreenTip:="Imported File Number " & FileListRow + 1, _
        TextToDisplay:=OpenFileName(i)
        rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0).Font.Name = "Calibri"
        rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0).Font.Size = 9
        rngFileList.Offset(FileListRow, 0).Font.Color = RGB(0, 0, 255)

        FileListRow = FileListRow + 1

        Next i

    ' Auto fit the width of columns for RAW Data
    Worksheets("Raw Data").Columns("A:Z").EntireColumn.AutoFit

    ' Timer Stop (calculate the length of time this sub-routine took to complete)
    SecondsElapsed = Round(Timer - StartTime, 2)

    ' Turn screen updating and auto calculating back on since file processing is now complete
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

    ' Display a message to report the sub-routine processing time after file selection including the number of data rows that have been imported
    MsgBox "AOI Inspection Results processed and imported in " & SecondsElapsed & " seconds" & " ." & vbNewLine & _
           "      Successfully imported " & (TargetRow) & " rows of data.", vbInformation, "Data Import Results"

' Reset to defaults in the event of a processing error during the sub-routine execution
ErrorHandler:
    Application.StatusBar = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

    ' Display a message to user including error code in the event of an error during execution
    MsgBox "An error number " & Err.Number & " was encountered!" & vbNewLine & _
           "Part or all of this VBA script was not completed.", vbInformation, "Error Message"
    End If

End Sub
```

Any ideas or suggestions for a better approach would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, there's a lot of text and information in your post.  Can you please parse down to an [mcve], focusing on the aspects of the code that aren't working?

Answer (score 4):

As mentioned in my comment, there's a lot going on in your post.  However, focusing on this

> I am now trying to define the parent folder as a variable, allow the user to input the subfolder name using Application.InputBox, then automatically import the data from all .txt files in the user-specified subfolder.

I have a solution - you can create an array that stores each file (both the path and file name), which you should be able to use to get the file names and then do whatever you need:

```
Sub import_files()
Dim files As String
Dim parentDir As String

parentDir = InputBox("Please input the directory you want to import files from")
If parentDir = "" Then Exit Sub 'If they hit "Cancel" or don't put anything.
' parentDir = GetFolder() 'UNCOMMENT THIS if you want the user to select a folder via "Windows Explorer"
files = LoopThroughFiles(parentDir, "txt")
' Debug.Print (files)

Dim iFiles() As String
iFiles() = Split(files, ",")

Dim i As Long
For i = LBound(iFiles) To UBound(iFiles)
    If iFiles(i) <> "" Then
        Debug.Print ("File located: " + parentDir + "\" + iFiles(i))
        ' THIS IS YOUR ARRAY, `iFILES`, SO HERE IS WHERE YOU DO STUFF
    End If
Next i

End Sub
Private Function LoopThroughFiles(inputDirectoryToScanForFile, filenameCriteria) As String
'https://stackoverflow.com/a/45749626/4650297
Dim tmpOut As String
    Dim StrFile As String
    'Debug.Print "in LoopThroughFiles. inputDirectoryToScanForFile: ", inputDirectoryToScanForFile
    StrFile = Dir(inputDirectoryToScanForFile & "\*" & filenameCriteria)
    Do While Len(StrFile) > 0
        ' Debug.Print StrFile
        tmpOut = tmpOut + "," + StrFile
        StrFile = Dir
    Loop
    LoopThroughFiles = tmpOut
End Function
Function GetFolder() As String
' https://stackoverflow.com/a/26392703/4650297
    Dim fldr As FileDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = Application.DefaultFilePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```

Edit: I added a method to have the user select the folder via a more "traditional" Windows Explorer type window, instead of pasting in a path string.  Either one should work for you though, let me know any questions.