# Saving an excel file based on prepopulated cells

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I made a Commandbutton that will allow the user to save the file based on the values within the excel cells in which the cells are pre-populated to begin with. Also how do you implement this fuction `GetSaveAsFilename` so the user can choose a save destination but not change the title. But I am getting an error executing this code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
Sub SaveMyWorkbook()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\"

    strPath = strFolderPath & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C7").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C8").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C45").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C9").Value & ".xlsm"

End Sub
```

Comment: Which error do you get? What have you tried so far?

Comment: What is "DoNotPrint - Setup"?

Comment: You have two nested Subs there....

Comment: @dwirony it looks like its going the be name of the workbook.

Comment: @dwirony I have multiple worksheets and one of them is called  "DoNotPrint - Setup" where the values come from

Comment: The error is am getting is "Expected end sub" but if I do add another end sub same error

Comment: That error is because as @TimWilliams mentioned.  You have `End Sub` at the end of the code twice.

Comment: Even If I remove an extra "End Sub" getting same error and also the "Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()" is highlighted yellow

Comment: You will need to remove `Sub SaveMyWorkbook()` as well since it is not needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on Tim's and Zack's Answer, this worked

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\"


With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")

    strPath = strFolderPath & .Range("C7").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C8").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C45").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C9").Value & ".xlsm"
    End With
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        .FilterIndex = 2

            If .Show = -1 Then .Execute
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

Best guess:

```
With Thisworkbook.sheets("DoNotPrint - Setup")

    strPath = strFolderPath & .Range("C7").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C8").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C45").Value & " " & _
                              .Range("C9").Value & ".xlsm"

End with
```

Selecting a folder to save to:

[VBA EXCEL To Prompt User Response to Select Folder and Return the Path as String Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392482/vba-excel-to-prompt-user-response-to-select-folder-and-return-the-path-as-string)

Answer (score 1):

To allow the user to choose the folder I use this:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

    Dim strPath As String
    Dim strFolderPath As String

    strFolderPath = "C:\Users\"

    strPath = strFolderPath & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C7").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C8").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C45").Value & " " & _
        DoNotPrint - Setup.Range("C9").Value & ".xlsm"

    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogSaveAs)
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialFileName = strPath
        .FilterIndex = 2
        .Title = Place Title Here if you want
            If .Show = -1 Then .Execute
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is there a way for you to implement ".range" values I have included above so the file name is automated?

Comment: Getting "Run-time error 424 Object required", I removed the ".Title" because " .Initial file name"  is the same thing

Comment: VBA is not going to like implicitly using worksheet names as objects. Look at the answer by Tim Williams for a worksheet object creation.

Comment: I completely overlooked that part @MarkBalhoff.  Thanks for pointing that out.