# Macro Excel import single sheet from various files

Tags: excel, vba

I have a macro excel file that does some clean up on cells and I need to import a single sheet from various files on the same folder. For example I need the sheet1 from all the excel files located on the same folder as my macro file. I have a code to do that manually but I need to be able to do it automatically either by selecting the files or running another macro to select them no matter the amount of files on the folder.

```
Sub Carga_Masiva()

Dim fName As String, wb As Workbook
fName = Application.GetOpenFilename("Excel Files (*.xl*), *.xl*")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)
    For Each sh In wb.Sheets
        If Application.CountA(sh.Cells) > 0 Then
            sh.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    wb.Close False
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can use `Dir()` to loop over all files in a folder, and `ThisWorkbook.Path` will give you the location of the folder where the file with the currently-running VBA is saved.  For examples see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10380312/loop-through-files-in-a-folder-using-vba

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd prompt user for a folder and then iterate over each file except the one with your macro.

To prompt for a folder use this solution (in my code as optional variant): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26392482/vba-excel-to-prompt-user-response-to-select-folder-and-return-the-path-as-string/26392703)

Complete code below:

```
Sub Carga_Masiva()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim fName As String, wb As Workbook
fName = Application.GetOpenfnamename("Excel fnames (*.xl*), *.xl*")
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fName)

For Each sh In wb.Sheets
    If Application.CountA(sh.Cells) > 0 Then
        sh.Copy Before:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
        Exit For
    End If
Next
wb.Close False
    
End Sub

Sub CopyToThisWorkbook()
    Dim wbMacro, wb As Workbook
    Set wbMacro = ThisWorkbook
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim folderPath, fName, tabName As String
    
    folderPath = wbMacro.Path & Application.PathSeparator
    
    'Prompt variant
    'folderPath = GetFolder & Application.PathSeparator
    fName = Dir(PathName:=folderPath)
    
    Do
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
        'Open all files except the one with macro
        If fName <> wbMacro.Name Then
            'Your code
            Set wb = Workbooks.Open(wbMacro.Path & "\" & fName)
            For Each sh In wb.Sheets
                If Application.CountA(sh.Cells) > 0 Then
                    tabName = sh.Name & "_" & Right(wb.Name, 10) 'Optional - rename Worksheet to be copied
                    sh.Name = tabName 'Optional
                    sh.Copy Before:=wbMacro.Sheets(1) 
                Exit For
                End If
            Next sh
            wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
        End If
       
        fName = Dir
    Loop Until fName = ""
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
End Sub

Function GetFolder() As String 'Optional variant
    Dim fldr As fnameDialog
    Dim sItem As String
    Set fldr = Application.fnameDialog(msofnameDialogFolderPicker)
    With fldr
        .Title = "Select a Folder"
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .InitialfnameName = Application.DefaultfnamePath
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        sItem = .SelectedItems(1)
    End With
NextCode:
    GetFolder = sItem
    Set fldr = Nothing
End Function
```