# How to import certain sheets out of workbooks into an other workbook from a folder? (VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, macros

Dear Stackoverflow members,

In the past i created with the help of stack overflow a dynamic import script. This script imports all the sheet's from workbooks in a folder.

But for now i want to only import sheets called 'sheet1', instead of all sheets from a workbook (sheet 1, 2 and 3).

I tried to slightly modify the 'worksheets' variable, but i couldn't get it to work.

The code consist of a macro script and a function:
This is the Sub

```
Public Sub Import_sheets_from_dir()
' Import script from http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/import-sheets.html
' Function script from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start
On Error GoTo ErrMsg
Dim directory As String
Dim fileName As String
Dim Sheet As Worksheet
Set ActivoWB = ActiveWorkbook

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

directory = GetFolderName() & "/"
fileName = Dir(directory & "*.xl??")

Do While fileName <> ""
    Workbooks.Open (directory & fileName)

    For Each Sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
        Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets(Sheet.Name).Copy _
        After:=ActivoWB.Sheets(ActivoWB.Sheets.Count)
    Next Sheet

    Workbooks(fileName).Close
    fileName = Dir()
Loop

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlerts = True

Exit Sub

ErrMsg:
MsgBox prompt:="your doing something wrong"


End Sub
```

This is the used function:

```
Public Function GetFolderName(Optional OpenAt As String) As String
Dim lCount As Long

GetFolderName = vbNullString

With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    .InitialFileName = OpenAt
    .Show
    For lCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        GetFolderName = .SelectedItems(lCount)
    Next lCount
End With
End Function
```

I also wonder which name is more relevant to change, i would like to use the VBA name like (the red, instead of the blue (is sheet name displayed in Excel)).
[Print Screen from VBA window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKoVn.png)
I would like to learn what would be the difference in coding for both.

I tried to modify the loop `For Each Sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Sheet1`, but this didn't work.

Can you please guide me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Regards,
Dubblej

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couldn't it be as simple as:

```
For Each Sheet In Workbooks(fileName).Worksheets
    If (Sheet.Name = "Sheet1") Then
        Sheet.Copy _
        After:=ActivoWB.Sheets(ActivoWB.Sheets.Count)
    Endif
Next Sheet
```

Comment: Thank you @Paul Ogilvie the second option you posted, works like a charm!!