# VBA code to find and open a folder based on its name

Tags: ms-access, vba

Essentially what I am trying to do is use vba to find and open a folder based on its name. I have looked everywhere and cannot find the solution. This is what

I have so far but nothing happens. I would like for the user to click a cmd button and it opens directly to a movie folder.

C:\Storage\Video\Video Folders\Genre\"Folder"\"movie title, Year"

the folder path after Video Folders can change depending on the "movie title, year"

```
Dim fso, Folder, subFlds, fld, s, showFolder as Object

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set Folder = fso.GetFolder(Path)
Set subFlds = Folder.SubFolders

s = "C:\Storage\Video\Video Folders"
For Each fld In subFlds
    s = s & Me.FolderName
    s = s & "<br />"
Next
showFolder = s
Application.FollowHyperlink showFolder
```

Comment: Why not use a folder picker ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Folder Picker - set where to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start)

Comment: What do you end up with in variable `s` when this is finished? If there is more than one subfolder it seems like this would write out some oddball garbage into that `s` variable.

Comment: My intention was for the user to click a cmd button and it opens directly to the folder with the specified movie title. In Video Folders the movies, there are sub folders by genre and then within the genre movie folder which contains the movie file and subtitles

Comment: I get run time error 91

Comment: do you want to open the `Video Folders` folder or some folders inside of it?

Comment: So many errors. Why are you trying to open multiple folders with one hyperlink? Why are you assigning a string to an object and then trying to assign the object to the Hyperlink method? You'll get an error on the line before FollowHyperlink as well as on the FollowHyperlink line

Comment: @Ibo trying to open some folders inside of it. dbmitch I was trying to use fso to get the path of the folder based on the name  then use hyperlink to open that path but i may have been way over my head and really hoping someone could help

Comment: btw, this one liner is not a good idea: Dim fso, Folder, subFlds, fld, s, showFolder as Object. Only the last declared variable is an object, the others are of type variant. This one liner actually is translated to: Dim fso as Variant, Folder as Variant ... showFolder as Object

Comment: @Ibo What value do you get with Me.FolderName? Is that the name of the folder you want to look for inside fso.GetFolder(Path)? And what is the value of Path? Would be good to add an example with some real values to your question and not only placeholders.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code

- to look for a folder by name in a path including subfolders of subfolders
- and then open that path in the file explorer.

I created a separate function to be able to call it recursively (to look in subfolders of subfolders ...)

Use this to call the main function:

```
Sub openFolderIfFound()
    Dim path As String
    Dim folderName As String
    Dim folderPath As String

    path = "C:\Storage\Video\Video Folders"
    folderName = Me.FolderName
    ' Example: folderName = "Seven Samurai - 1954"
    ' Example using wildcards: folderName = "*Samurai*"
    folderPath = lookForFolderInPath(path, folderName)
    If folderPath <> "" Then Application.FollowHyperlink folderPath
    ' Note: in Excel use ThisWorkbook.FollowHyperlink folderPath
End Sub
```

Main function to look for a folder:

```
' Look for folder by name in path (including subfolders of subfolders)
' and return the path of the folder if it was found.
'
' Args:
'   path (String): Path to look in.
'   folderName (String): Name of folder to look for. Uses LIKE operator for comparison to enable the use of wildcards:
'     https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/like-operator
' Returns:
'   Path of folder if found else empty String ""
Function lookForFolderInPath(path As String, folderName As String, Optional ByRef fso As Object) As String
    Dim topFolder As Object
    Dim subfolders As Object
    Dim folder As Object
    Dim i As Long

    If fso Is Nothing Then Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set topFolder = fso.GetFolder(path)
    Set subfolders = topFolder.subfolders

    ' Check if permission to access subfolders
    On Error Resume Next
    i = subfolders.Count
    On Error GoTo 0
    If i <> 0 Then
        ' Loop through subfolders of folder (path)
        For Each folder In subfolders
            If folder.Name Like folderName Then
                ' Return folder path if folder name matched subfolder name
                lookForFolderInPath = folder.path
                Exit For
            Else
                ' Recursively call function to check subfolders in subfolders
                lookForFolderInPath = lookForFolderInPath(folder.path, folderName, fso)
                ' Exit loop if folder was found
                If lookForFolderInPath <> "" Then Exit For
            End If
        Next
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing
    Set folder = Nothing
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you want to select the folder you want to open, but the key part is this one line that will solve your problem. Simply pass the path of the folder you want to open and it will do it and will activate the window for the user:

```
Sub OpenFolder(sPath)
    Call Shell("explorer.exe" & " " & sPath, vbNormalFocus)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the call shell that @Ibo recommended and this worked for me or rather its as close as I could get

Sub cmd_folder_Click()
  Dim Folder As String, s As String, loc As String

```
   s = "search-ms:query="
   loc = "&crumb=location:C:\Storage\Video\Video Folders\"
   Call Shell("explorer.exe " & Chr(34) & s & Me.Folder & loc & Chr(34), vbNormalFocus)
```

End Sub

Comment: why don't you simply use `C:\Storage\Video\Video Folders` for the path? If you tell us exactly what you want to do then it will be a lot easier to come up with a more complete code. I understood you have one folder than contains subfolders that each of them contain some videos of a certain genre. Is the button only ONE button or you want to put button for each genre? Do you want to put one button that opens up the folder based on the name of the video etc?