# Specify Path in Excel VBA when running Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am having and using this code for (part of it) for some transformations/filtering from certain files to certain files, plus some filtering on sheets and so on... Everything works good for me, but the colleagues from the work wanna also use this code on their PC*s, and there is a problem at start, it has to be edited in the code (path, location) so that someone else can use it - and I dont wanna that anyone from outside have an access to the code easily (ok theyre not skilled but still), so that can mess it up and make it crap what is possible.

Question, is there any line of code that gives like popup message simply asking to define from where you wanna take certain files to where? to avoid going into code and change from there? I hope I was clear enough...

```
Dim FileSystem As Object
Dim HostFolder As String

' *** Folder with systems to define (path) ***
 HostFolder = "Q:\Objekt\Kundenerklärung\OSRAM\Converter"

' *** If folder is empty/full message ***``
Dim fs, strFolderPath, oFolder
Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

strFolderPath = "Q:\Objekt\Kundenerklärung\OSRAM\Converter\" ' *** This is 
your folder to define ***
Set oFolder = fs.GetFolder(strFolderPath)
 If (oFolder.SubFolders.Count = 0) Then
 ' * Folder is Empty *
   MsgBox "Folder is empty!"
 Else
 ' * Folder isn't empty *
   MsgBox "Folder not empty. Subfolders count: " & oFolder.SubFolders.Count
 End If

 Set fs = Nothing

 Set FileSystem = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 DoFolder FileSystem.GetFolder(HostFolder)

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
 Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [VBA - Folder Picker - set where to start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can ask for an input value as such:

```
strFolderPath = InputBox("What folder would you like to use?")
```

A more user-friendly solution would be to use a [file dialog box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19372319/vba-folder-picker-set-where-to-start), though it's somewhat more involved.

Comment: Well, it didnt work well...I mean it asks for path but then makes error in my line already,  *** Folder with systems to define (path) ***
 HostFolder = "Q:\Objekt\Kundenerklärung\OSRAM\Converter"

Is there posibility to completely change those locations on "input method"? So to ask from which path/folder should take files for convert and where to save after ? ...unfortunately I am not good in Macros/Vba stuff....

Comment: You put in this value, and it generates an error?: Q:\Objekt\Kundenerklärung\OSRAM\Converter\

Comment: I don't know why you have variables HostFolder AND strFolderPath. Aren't they always the same value?

Comment: I did lit ong ago-cant even remember, it was ment to be always in the same directory, without changing anything, but nowadays I have to change it, to make it simpler. BUt I tried to delete that line, gives me errors, they have to be both, otherwise cant open anything.

Comment: What is this code meant to do? Just tell you whether a folder has subfolders or not? And if it does, tell you how many?

Comment: Okay, code has to do lots of same operations, converting lots of files (.dif file) to .txt file and reducing some columns. So its always the same. Input files we are getting in more folders, which are in one folder before using macro - so It HAS subfolders. Code tells for info how many subs are inside and when I click OK, Macro is doing converting then... 

My question was only to skip defining Locations when someone wanna use it, or third person if wanna use it,  path of input and output files has to be changed manually in code - I wanna be able to define it immediately jsut before Macro...